# Navbar not collapsing and expanding properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

trying to work out navbars right now, but my code doesn't seem to work with them.

The collapse icon is staying next to the navbar-brand and then the navbar-links are sitting next to it.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

    <title>Website</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav id="mainNavbar "class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TEST</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-links">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="navbar-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-links">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TICKETS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your **button** change your class navbar-toggle to **navbar-toggler**

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-links">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="navbar-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add navbar-toggler class instead of navbar-toggle to the button see the code:

```
 <nav id="mainNavbar "class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TEST</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-links">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="navbar-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-links">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TICKETS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```